# How to solve this "module can not find" error in IDE window?

Tags: python, pycharm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sy2Oi.png)

As you can see, I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: In the future, you may want to provide a little more context, as well as attempts that you've made to remedy the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that you are having this issue is because you are trying to access the `config` module in the wrong way.

I can see that you have placed your `config.py` file inside of your `templates` folder. What you need to do is take it out of the `template` folder, and place it in the same directory as your `app.py` file.

Once you do this, you will be able to import it in `app.py`.